# Tikz Tree Spacing in a Subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, tikz-trees

I have been trying to create decision trees in a subfigure format as below, but not matter what kind of spacing I try, there are always over-lapping nodes at some point or another. In the example below, I have two copies of the same tree as an example. How can I fix this using the tikz package? Also, is there any advice that I can have for drawing slightly larger trees using the tikz package as well? It is very frustrating, because I feel like I am at the point of just changing the level/sibling distances at random in order to try and get things to work...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, level distance=25mm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=80mm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=30mm}]
\node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_1}$}
    child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_2}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_4}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_2} \gets 1$}} 
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_4}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_4} \gets 0$}} 
        }   
    }
    child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_3}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_2}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$\begin{aligned} x\smash{_1} &\gets 0 \\ x\smash{_3} &\gets 1 \end{aligned}$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$\begin{aligned} x\smash{_1} &\gets 0 \\ x\smash{_2} &\gets 0 \end{aligned}$}}  
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_4}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_4} \gets 1$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_3} \gets 0$}} 
        }   
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A Tree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, level distance=25mm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=80mm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=30mm}]
\node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_1}$}
    child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_2}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_4}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_2} \gets 1$}} 
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_4}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_4} \gets 0$}} 
        }   
    }
    child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_3}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_2}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$\begin{aligned} x\smash{_1} &\gets 0 \\ x\smash{_3} &\gets 1 \end{aligned}$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$\begin{aligned} x\smash{_1} &\gets 0 \\ x\smash{_2} &\gets 0 \end{aligned}$}}  
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$x\smash{_4}$}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_4} \gets 1$}}
            child{node[rectangle, draw]{$x\smash{_3} \gets 0$}} 
        }   
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{B Tree}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\label{datftt}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, there's a minimum width of the trees that arises from the text inside the leaf (end) nodes. For both trees, you can see that placing all the `x_n <- 1` end to end results already takes over half the text width.  If you want to force those trees to be side-by-side, you'll either have overlapping trees (as you currently do), or overlapping nodes.  Neither options being elegant...

This minimum width can be slightly adjusted by having a smaller font size for lower levels so that they take less space when placed side-by-side.  This can be achieved with the `level n/.style={font=\footnotesize}`.

You also mention that you keep having to use trial and error adjusting the sibling distances.  The reason is that the standard tree construction algorithm in Ti*k*Z has very little foresight.  It sees that the next level has `n` nodes and places them according to the sibling distance, but it has no idea whether or not these nodes have many more nodes underneath them making the effective 'width' of the node larger.

This can be fixed by using the `graph drawing` library from Ti*k*Z.  It offers many more algorithms to automatically place nodes which makes drawing [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics))
 much much simpler.  I have included an example that shows how to use the graph drawing library:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  graphdrawing,
}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \tikz \graph [
      tree layout,
      nodes={
        draw,
        circle,
      },
      level 3/.style={
        font=\small,
      },
      level 4/.style={
        nodes={
          rectangle,
          font=\footnotesize,
        }
      }
    ] {
      "\(x_{}\)"
        -> {
          "\(x_{1}\)"
          -> {
            "\(x_{11}\)"
            -> {
              "\(x_{111}\)",
              "\(x_{112}\)"
            },
            "\(x_{12}\)"
            -> {
              "\(x_{121}\)",
              "\(x_{122}\)"
            }
          },
          "\(x_{2}\)"
          -> {
            "\(x_{21}\)"
            -> {
              "\(x_{211}\)",
              "\(x_{212}\)"
            },
            "\(x_{22}\)"
            -> {
              "\(x_{221}\)",
              "\(x_{222}\)"
            }
          }
        }
    };
    \caption{Tree \(x\)}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \tikz \graph [
      tree layout,
      nodes={
        draw,
        circle,
      },
      level 3/.style={
        font=\small,
      },
      level 4/.style={
        nodes={
          rectangle,
          font=\footnotesize,
        }
      }
    ] {
      "\(y_{}\)"
        -> {
          "\(y_{1}\)"
          -> {
            "\(y_{11}\)"
            -> {
              "\(y_{111}\)",
              "\(y_{112}\)"
            },
            "\(y_{12}\)"
            -> {
              "\(y_{121}\)",
              "\(y_{122}\)"
            }
          },
          "\(y_{2}\)"
          -> {
            "\(y_{21}\)"
            -> {
              "\(y_{211}\)",
              "\(y_{212}\)"
            },
            "\(y_{22}\)"
            -> {
              "\(y_{221}\)",
              "\(y_{222}\)"
            }
          }
        }
    };
    \caption{Tree \(y\)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{My awesome captions for trees!}
  \label{fig:trees}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image: output]